# Is it safe to access a struct using pointer pointed to unaligned memory address in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, struct, memcpy, memory-alignment

```
struct CustomData
{
    char flag;
    int count;
    double value;
};

CustomData custom_data{};

char *buf = new char[sizeof(CustomData) + 3];
memcpy(buf + 3, &custom_data, sizeof(CustomData));

CustomData* ptr = (CustomData *)(buf + 3);

ptr->count = 10;
ptr->value = 20.0;
```

I have a memory buffer composed with some header bytes and a struct. The struct is memcpy to this memory buffer. I have to modify some fields in this embeded struct, as demostrated above.

My questions are:

1. Is this a safe access on x86-64? How about other platforms?
2. `memcpy` to a local struct, modify it and copy it back is surely OK, but it seems wasteful. Is there a way to check if `ptr` is properly aligned for safe-access to the struct?

Comment: please pick one language

Comment: this code is undefined according to C (assuming replacing `new` with `malloc`) standards due to violation of strict aliasing rule

Comment: @tstanisl: Per C 2018 6.5 6, allocating memory dynamically and filling it with data by using `memcpy` or copying using character types creates an object with the effective type of the original data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, right, I got biased by `new` that sets the type of the object.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you mean it is different between C and C++? I don't even know there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the C nor the C++ standards define the behavior of accessing memory without the alignment required for the lvalue type, nor even of converting a pointer to another pointer type when the pointer value does not have the alignment required for the destination type. The question is not whether your target architecture (x86-64 or other) supports misaligned access but whether your C or C++ implementation, particularly the compiler, supports it.

Looking at your sample code, I suspect it is a proxy for copying data into a buffer from a network or file or other source, then attempting to interpret part of that data as a desired type, possibly after inspecting a header in the received data to determine the type and/or the location of the subject data. If so, you should describe the original situation, because the proxy code you showed is insufficient.

When reading raw data as bytes from a network or file, it is preferable to read the data directly into the desired structure. Ideally, the communication protocol would be specified to align the data as needed so that no further manipulation is needed once the data is received into an aligned buffer. In C, unions may help deal with issues of aliasing one type of data as another.

Failing the direct-into-structure method, `memcpy` may be used, and it may not be as inefficient as you think because the `memcpy` method results in code with well-defined behavior and then the compiler often can, given sufficient visibility to the relevant parts of the code, optimize the assembly it generates so that no actual `memcpy` occurs.

Failing that, some compilers have various extensions to the C and C++ standards that let you define structure types without alignment requirements and to access memory using arbitrary types (supporting aliasing character arrays as other types).

In C at least, dynamically allocated memory can be filled with data using a character type and then accessed as another type following rules regarding “effective types.” However, certain rules about aliasing must be followed, and this does not enable accessing incorrectly aligned data (absent use of the extensions mentioned above).

Comment: I read from another module (using shared file) and it give me a buffer, for each record, that starts with some fields and then follows a struct. In my stage, I have to change some fields in the struct, and write it to others. I know there are some serialization protocols, such as potobuf, but I think we can not switch to them according to our current situation (lots of work).

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer punning is dangerous as it possible break the strict-aliasing rules.

You need to use `memcpy`. Most optimizing compilers know `memcpy` very well and usually do not emit the actual call to the `memcpy`:

```
typedef struct CustomData
{
    char flag;
    int count;
    double value;
}CustomData;


CustomData *foo(int val, double d)
{
    char *buf = new char[sizeof(CustomData) + 3];

    CustomData cd;

    cd.count = val;
    cd.value = d;

    memcpy(buf + 3, &cd, sizeof(cd));
    return (CustomData *)buf;
}
```

```
foo(int, double):
        push    rbp
        mov     ebp, edi
        mov     edi, 19
        push    rbx
        sal     rbp, 32
        movq    rbx, xmm0
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+3], rbp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+11], rbx
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: I tried on VS 2019 and it seems to be compiler dependent behavior. On VS 2019, `memcpy` is transformed to `movups` and `movsd` SSE instructions.

Comment: @guanboshen how it is optimized is up to compiler and platform of course

Comment: and it is up to the code we write also. I tried this morning, and finally I think it is only safe to define a proper wrapper structure for all leading fields and the struct itself.